# Restangular : addResponseInterceptor not working

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am working on angularjs project.

In **app.js** I used **addResponseInterceptor** to intercept every request to the server. If there is no error **(response.status == 200 OK)** in response then it works perfect. But I want to intercept particularly when **(response.status == 401)**. In this case I want to redirect user to the login page. But it's not working.

Here is my **app.js** addResponseInterceptor's code :

```
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        if (response.status === 401)
        {
            window.location = 'To the login page';
        } else
        {
            var extractedData;
            extractedData = data;
            return extractedData;
        }
    });
```

I got these error when request refuse to get data

[image]

I tried to debug the response by "**console.log(response)**" But It not displaying anything. It seems like if there is error in response then it not entering into thr interceptor block.

Comment: you need to add errorResponseIntercetpor in case of error

Comment: @entre : How can I add errorResponseIntercetpor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need is error-intecetpr. example below

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
    if(response.status === 403) {
        refreshAccesstoken().then(function() {
            // Repeat the request and then call the handlers the usual way.
            $http(response.config).then(responseHandler, deferred.reject);
            // Be aware that no request interceptors are called this way.
        });

        return false; // error handled
    }

    return true; // error not handled
});
```